# java.NullPointerException in a for loop

Tags: java, mockito

The function to be mocked is of class ContactsProductionService.java

```
@Override
public ContactsProductionDto getContactsProduction(long id) {
     Site       site    = siteDao.find(id);
     ContactsProductionDto contactsProductionDto = new ContactsProductionDto();

        List<Entite> entities = entiteDao.findEntitesByType(Type.CP);
        for (Entite entite : entities) {
            ProductionCenterDto productionCenter = new ProductionCenterDto();
            productionCenter.setId(entite.getId());
            productionCenter.setCode(entite.getCode());
            productionCenter.setNumber(entite.getNumero());
            productionCenter.setName(entite.getDescription());
            contactsProductionDto.getProductionCenters().add(productionCenter);
        }return contactsProductionDto;
```

And this is the test:

```
@Test
public void testGetContactsProduction(){
    Mockito.when(siteDao.find(id)).thenReturn(new Site());
    List<Entite> entities = null;
    Mockito.when(entiteDao.findEntitesByType(Type.CP)).thenReturn(entities);
    ContactsProductionDto contact=contactsProductionService.getContactsProduction(id);
    Assert.assertNotNull(contact);
}
```

I'm getting NullPointerException on running this test. The cause is that inside the for loop value of Entite is null!!
Any help please :(

Comment: you mean `entities`?

Comment: Having written that shouldn't help you: `List<Entite> entities = null;`

Comment: your test sets the list to `null` and then you try to loop with a for-each on it.

Comment: Modify `List<Entite> entities = null;` line by `List<Entite> entities = new LinkedList<Entite>();`. Does it help ?

Comment: @soufrk thx i fixed it with List<Entite> entities =  new ArrayList<Entite>();